# #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' 7

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting this error and not being savvy with creating tables and columns some of the other similar problems and answers haven't helped.

This is the error:

```
Error
```

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO orders_session_info 
(txn_signature , orders_id , payment , payment_title , payment_amount , payment_currency , payment_currency_val , sendto , billto , language , language_id , currency , currency_value , firstname , lastname , content_type , affiliate_id , affiliate_date , affiliate_browser, affiliate_ipaddress , affiliate_clickthroughs_id )
VALUES 
(
'd4208b15558a761c34dc7c79b87275b4', '20167', 'paypal', 'PayPal', '273.56', 'USD', '1.00000000', '140', '140', 'english', '1', 'USD', '1.00000000', 'Pauls', 'Dandzbergs', 'physical', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', '0'
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

And the code:

```
-- Table structure for table `orders_session_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders_session_info;
CREATE TABLE orders_session_info (
  txn_signature int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  orders_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  payment varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  payment_title varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
  payment_amount varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  payment_currency varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  payment_currency_val varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  sendto varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  billto varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  language varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  language_id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  currency varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  currency_value varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  firstname varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  lastname varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  content_type varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  affiliate_id varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  affiliate_date varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  affiliate_browser varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  affiliate_ipaddress varchar(128) NOT NULL,    
  affiliate_clickthroughs_id varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (txn_signature),
  KEY txn_signature(orders_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

any specific help would be much appreciated...

```
--
-- Dumping data for table orders_session_info
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary key field `txn_signature` is an `auto increment` field. This means the database will create a unique value for it automatically when you insert a new row.

Therefore you should not include this field in your INSERT statement - the database will take care of it for you. Right now it thinks you're trying to override the automatic functionality and insert a value of "d4208b15558a761c34dc7c79b87275b4" manually. Obviously this would result in duplicate IDs once you have more than one row, so it's not allowed. Also, your field is an int and you're trying to insert a string into it, which will never work either.

Comment: ...and the server doesn't have an appropriately strict `@@SQL_MODE` enabled, so strings that don't start with a digit are simply coerced to the integer value 0. (+1)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the addition, I didn't know that.